# How do I split a table into multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql, split

I'd like to split my current HUGE table into multiple tables. The new tables should be split according to an they entry on a specific field.

E.g. if the field is Gender with each record selected as male and female, id like two tables one for male the other female.

```
Old table:
Gender   First Name     Last Name   
Male     John           Smith
Female   Sally          Smith 


New tables:
Name: Male
Gender   First Name     Last Name   
Male     John           Smith

Name: Female
Gender   First Name     Last Name   
Female   Sally          Smith
```

Except the field is city. Rather than name each city separately within the code, id like all the same cities to be picked up and grouped into an individual tables. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Splitting tables is generally a really bad idea.

Comment: Seems like a very bad idea. Keep it as one, single table!

Comment: Agreed with the above comments. If you are running into speed issues, you might want to look into indexing.

Comment: post your actual table structure. This busness about cities and genders is rather confusing.

Comment: If you are splitting the table into two by genders, you would not need the gender field in the new table, rather you could name the tables 'male' and 'female'. That said, what you are doing is likely a terrible idea and will turn any queries and maintenance you do into a nightmare.

Comment: You do NOT want to do this. It will have very little impact on performance, if any, and will be much harder to code for.

Answer (score 1):

First query:

```
Insert into Table2 select * from Table1 where gender = 'female'
```

Second query:

```
Delete from Table1 where gender = 'female'
```

Anyway, I would do some research to understand if table splitting is really needed for your case, or if it just increase the DB structure (and relative code) complexity

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking can be accomplished using partitioning. Since you are using MySQL then you need to checkout list partitioning specifically as it will partition the table according to the specified values. You can still use the same queries but the database will automatically use the underlying correct partition.

Comment: The question is tagged with MySQL.